# Attach PDF to flow from SharePoint list matching employee number

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, microsoft-flow

I've been tasked with creating a flow that will send an email to all our staff with custom attachments.

A typical attachment would be in this format: "John.Smith-123456789.PDF" (FirstName.LastName-EmployeeNumber)

As we have approximately 1500 staff there are cases where we have duplicate names so simply cannot extract the name from the file and match it to a username.

I had a theory that if we have a list of All names, email addresses and employee numbers we could then match the employee number in the filename against the one in the list and send an email to the email address associated with the employee number attaching the PDF file.

What is the best way of doing this as I dont yet have the PDF files.

This is how my current flow looks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your library where you store pdf needs to have some unique value (additional metadata column) you could identify the right entry. You could use the email address as those need to be unique (or the employee number).

Comment: I will be getting a list of all employee names, email addresses and employee ID's. 
I'm thinking I should create a SharePoint list and pre-populate this with these details - I'm just wondering when a file is added into the document library. ie. John-Smith-123456789.PDF how can I (once the file is added) get flow to query the SharePoint list, pull the details and populate the fields in the document library so that flow can then add the document to the email that it sends to the end user?

Comment: You can use web service to query and then parse the response. The action is HTTP request to Sharepoint. You can find the web service details in MSDN